# CSS positioning: display a line of images of different ratios

Tags: css, image, flexbox, display, responsive-images

I want to make an image line with some specific and essential constraints.

Challenge: Images must all have the same height. But I do not care what height I get at the end. The image files have different ratios. Images must retain their original ratio.
The width of the line is the width of the screen. This width is therefore variable according to the user's device.
I would like it to work for n img; n∊[2;6]

The real challenge is that the behavior remains the same with small screen width !

I got a perfect result with flexbox below. But this code only works for firefox. With other browsers, I can not impose on the line the width of the screen and with, the reduction of the images to hold, or the images lose their ratio.

My attempt can be seen [on this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/neborion/pknm1wj6/15/)

HTML

```
<div>
    <img src="https://www.tlpro.fr/data/img/artspreview/4CroquisTim.jpg">
    <img src="https://www.tlpro.fr/data/img/artspreview/4SerresJardinDesPlantes01.jpg">
    <img src="https://www.tlpro.fr/data/img/artspreview/5Dessin6FranchissementRail2.jpg">
    <img src="https://www.tlpro.fr/data/img/artspreview/6bergersbiny08.jpg">
    <img src="https://www.tlpro.fr/data/img/artspreview/4house2.jpg">
</div>
```

CSS

```
body{padding:0px;margin:0px;background-color:#4c3b25;}
div{
    margin-top: 8px;
    border-top: #f9992a solid 5px;
    border-bottom: #f9992a solid 5px;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-around;
    max-height: 400px;
}
div>img{
    max-height: 400px;
    margin: 0px 10px;
    padding: 15px 0px;
}
```

Expected result can be seen here (img) : https://ask.tlpro.fr/stackoverflow/001/st001.jpg

Comment: Can the HTML be altered?

Comment: Thanks @Mike , Yes, we can add/remove as many canvas, wrappers or other things as we want. Only the result is important. I'm also open to background img, JS, Jquery, PHP, micro plug-in… I prefer not to use bootstrap or SASS if possible, but I'm not totaly closed. The simplest and elegant solution is just preferable. As usual.

Answer (score 0):

In your CSS, try adding `width:auto` in your `div>img` selector

Comment: Sorry, @Silverman42 . According to your advice, I tried several combinations again with this without success. If you get an interesting result as well, you can probably show it on fiddle / online / or just here. Thank you for having already taken time.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I could found is to set a different width to every image because the dimensions are different. With this approach you have the responsivness. Here is the result:

```css
  body { 
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
    background-color:#4c3b25;
  }
  
  div {
    margin-top:8px;
    border-top:#f9992a solid 5px;
    border-bottom:#f9992a solid 5px;
    width:100%;
    display:flex;
    align-items:center;
    justify-content:space-between;
    padding: 0 15px;
  }

  div > img {
    max-height:100%;
    padding:15px 0px;
    display: block;
  }

  div > img:nth-child(1) {
    width: 16%;
  }

  div > img:nth-child(2) {
    width: 21%;
  }

  div > img:nth-child(3) {
    width: 32%;
  }

  div > img:nth-child(4) {
    width: 14.3%;
  }

  div > img:nth-child(5) {
    width: 14.4%;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>

<body>

  <div>
    <img src="https://www.tlpro.fr/data/img/artspreview/4CroquisTim.jpg">
    <img src="https://www.tlpro.fr/data/img/artspreview/4SerresJardinDesPlantes01.jpg">
    <img src="https://www.tlpro.fr/data/img/artspreview/5Dessin6FranchissementRail2.jpg">
    <img src="https://www.tlpro.fr/data/img/artspreview/6bergersbiny08.jpg">
    <img src="https://www.tlpro.fr/data/img/artspreview/4house2.jpg">
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks you @A-papadakis , To this day, I use a thing like this. A combo with overflow and height to maintain ratio and keep the possibility of scroll the content so as not to lose it on both sides. Your proposal improves my craft. The perfect solution that I hope to find one day will be one where all the content fits the width on small screen width. Thx already !

Comment: So you want to be responsive with all images always visible?

Comment: That's the challenge, yes. It does not matter how small the images would be then. I wish I could do this so first. I will then ensure that the content will be readable.

Comment: Check the updated answer. I tested it localy and it works :)

Comment: Indeed. Thx again! However, getting a generalizable code to any image is also part of the challenge! We might want to dynamically change images for example! I'm trying your solution by integrating a javascript calculation to always get the right width.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I came up with. It seems to be working for me with Chrome:

```css
body {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  background-color: #4c3b25;
}

.container {
  margin-top: 8px;
  border-top: #f9992a solid 5px;
  border-bottom: #f9992a solid 5px;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.item {
  margin: 15px 3px;
}

.item img {
  max-height: 100px;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">
    <img src="https://www.tlpro.fr/data/img/artspreview/4CroquisTim.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="https://www.tlpro.fr/data/img/artspreview/4SerresJardinDesPlantes01.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="https://www.tlpro.fr/data/img/artspreview/5Dessin6FranchissementRail2.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="https://www.tlpro.fr/data/img/artspreview/6bergersbiny08.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="https://www.tlpro.fr/data/img/artspreview/4house2.jpg"></div>
</div>
```

The height of the container is controlled by the height of the images, not the other way around as you have it. Then I set the width of each image to 100%, which causes it to scale down when you run out of horizontal space.

I also added a bit of horizontal margin to the items to make sure that there is always a little bit of separation between them when the images get scaled down.

Comment: Keeping the ratio is the main constraint. Resizing all the images when the available width is missing would have been the second constraint. And the last constraint is the equality of heights between all the images. But your proposal seems to be saving. By calculating the sum of the widths with javascript, it must be possible to prevent the lack of space by modifying the unique value of .item img {max-height: ...;} CPU usage will remain miserable. If it works, it will be the perfect solution. I'm coming back soon with some code and maybe to close the subject.

Comment: @neborion That's why you use `max-height` and not `height`. This works with pure CSS. You don't need any javascript to alter `max-height` because when you resize down, the width constraint will automatically resize the height down as well.